# Specflow ms test runner to show log information in output window

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, specflow

I am running specflow using ms test runner.

I only see the output log of the test after the test has completed.  Is there a way to get the test to output log information while it's running?

Comment: Debug.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine should do the job.

Comment: Hi.  It doesn't output anything.  I only see output during debug mode.  In test results window,  is there a way to see results or logs of a test that's running

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question? I want to log ```Test Outcome``` and ```TestName ``` in a file

Answer (score 1):

TestContext.Progress.Write(""); This should do the job